# Obtaining multiple percentiles (percentile_cont equivalent) in one pass within Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, analytic-functions

I understand that we can rewrite `percentile_cont` within Teradata as:

```
SELECT
  part_col
  ,data_col
   + ((MIN(data_col) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col ORDER BY data_col ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) - data_col)
       * (((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col) - 1) * x) MOD 1)) AS percentile_cont
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part_col ORDER BY data_col)
    = CAST((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col) - 1) * x AS INT) + 1;
```

See [this very helpful discussion](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/06/missing-functions-percentile-disc-percentile-cont-median) for more information.

Understanding that replacing `x` with `0.90` would return the 90th percentile, is there an elegant way of extending this and returning multiple percentiles in one pass?

For example, say I want to extend this example and return the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentiles in one pass? Is this possible? Seems like I would need multiple `QUALIFY` statements? Similarly, if I desire multiple `GROUP BY` equivalents, is this akin to passing more columns in the `PARTITION BY`?

---

```
-- SQL:2008 Equivalent pseudo-code
SELECT
  part_col_a
 ,part_col_b
 ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_col) AS p25
 ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_col) AS p50
 ,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_col) AS p75
FROM tab
GROUP BY
  part_col_a
  ,part_col_b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fully read my blog, the final query is doing exactly what you want :-)

```
SELECT part_col
  ,MIN(pc25) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col) AS quartile_1
  ,MIN(pc50) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col) AS quartile_2
  ,MIN(pc75) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col) AS quartile_3
FROM
 (
  SELECT
    part_col
    ,COUNT(*)      OVER (PARTITION BY part_col) - 1 AS N
    ,ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY part_col ORDER BY data_col) - 1 AS rowno
    ,MIN(data_col) OVER (PARTITION BY part_col ORDER BY data_col ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) - data_col AS diff

    ,CASE
       WHEN rowno = CAST(N * 0.25 AS INT)
       THEN data_col +(((N * 0.25) MOD 1) * diff)
     END AS pc25

    ,CASE
       WHEN rowno = CAST(N * 0.50 AS INT)
       THEN data_col +(((N * 0.50) MOD 1) * diff)
     END AS pc50

    ,CASE
       WHEN rowno = CAST(N * 0.75 AS INT)
       THEN data_col +(((N * 0.75) MOD 1) * diff)
     END AS pc75
  FROM tab
  QUALIFY   rowno = CAST(N * 0.25 AS INT)
       OR   rowno = CAST(N * 0.50 AS INT)
       OR   rowno = CAST(N * 0.75 AS INT)
 ) AS dt
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part_col ORDER BY part_col) = 1
```